# Change font type and size of all section and subsection headings

Tags: titlesec, section-titles, unnumbered-sections

The font for **normal text should be Times New Roman**. But I want to change the **section and subsection headings to Uppercase-Arial-12 Size**.The MWE is shown below.

```
documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[left=1.25in,right=1.25in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathptmx}% Times Roman font
\title{My Title}
\date{}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: You've tagged this with `titlesec` but you're not loading the package. See [Change size of section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph and subparagraph title](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/59726) for the general idea of how to do this. `mathptmx` is deprecated, better to replace it with `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`.  If you need the exact fonts, use `xelatex` or `lualatex`. See [How do I set the document body to be Times New Roman and Section headings to be Arial?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/96631)

Comment: Please tell us if you free to use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX or if you must use pdfLaTeX to compile your document. Also, please advise if you absolutely must use Arial, which is a clone of Helvetica, or if you are free to use Helvetica. (Hint: Only font geeks can readily distinguish Arial and Helvetica, and only if certain letters (chiefly uppercase-R) are present.

Comment: If you want to use Times New Roman and Arial in PDFTeX, you can use `winfonts`. (I believe the bugs have been fixed?) There are also `newtxtext`/`newtxmath` and either `uarial` or `tgheros` as substitutes.

Comment: If you can, however, I would recommend `fontspec` or `unicode-math`.